# List items are not filling width of the ul

Tags: html, css

I have a list that I want to fill the width of the container but there seems to be a small gap at the end for some reason.

The CSS is lengthy so here is the html

```
<div class="line clearfix no-margin">
    <div class="container">
        <header>
            <div class="logo col-4">
                <img src="#" />
                 <h1 class="logo">Name</h1>

            </div>
            <div class="nav clearfix">
                <ul>
                    <li><span id="head-icon"></span>About Us</li>
                    <li><span id="wrench-icon"></span>Services</li>
                    <li><span id="email-icon"></span>Contact</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </header>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VRtnA/14/)

I can't seem to figure out where that gap is coming from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of the `margin-left: -3px;` in `.nav li`!

See the updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VRtnA/18/

Answer (score 1):

Try removing `margin-left: -3px;` in `.nav li`.